# mgwt IconHandler and color 3 digit HEX bug

Tags: css, gwt, colors, mgwt, cssresource

MGWT IconHandler has 2 implementations:

The second one: IconHandlerEmulatedImpl does not support 3 digit HEX color codes.

When I use a variable defined the css file like this:

```
@def BUTTON_COLOR #FFFFFF;
```

the MGWTCssResource (or CssResource) abbreviate it and returns:

```
#fff
```

Then, instead of white, my button gets blue (#000fff).

How to round this problem or how to stop abbreviating colors by CssResource?

Comment: In which browser do you see this problem? I used to see it in old IE.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed on master now and will be in the next release.
https://github.com/mgwt/mgwt/issues/220